# iPhone: How to fetch tweets which contain a particular word?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, twitter

How can I fetch tweets which contain a particular word?

For example : I want to fetch tweets from any user that contains "Bill Gates" as a part of their tweet.

How can it be done?

Any references to tutorials or good articles would be really great.

Comment: Have you read the Twitter API docs, or even used Twitter's own search?

Comment: @BoltClock: Yes I tried reading Twitter API. But I am not able to fetch tweets which contains particular word. What could be done? Can you please guide me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier than you think. Examples:

- Results in JSON: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=bill%20gates
- Results in ATOM XML: http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=bill%20gates
- ATOM XML for "Steve Jobs": http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=steve%20jobs

So it's the server http://search.twitter.com/ then the method *search*, then a dot and the format, *json* or *atom*, then the text you want to search for is the *q* parameter. Official documentation is [here](http://search.twitter.com/api/), and you can try them directly in your web browser to see the results — at least in Safari the JSON is shown unparsed and the ATOM is shown as a feed.

You can add additional filters (such as by geolocation or restricting yourself to certain languages) or perform other types of search (such as by user), as shown in the documentation.

To parse the result, you can throw the ATOM into the NSXMLParser and grab the parts you want or use the JSON with a third-party open source parser like [json-framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) or with whatever else you've got.

Comment: Ok Thanks!! I will try that and get back to you. :)

Comment: @tommy i am new to this. but is there a way to use the ne streaming api....bcz this REST api has a limitation. please help me...